# Alternative for 'disableOptionCentering' in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material

What I would like is for the Overlay pane position for the mat-select just to be below or above on it, instead of overlaying it on center by default.

I can use the disableOptionCentering property but it is not working for Angular 5 and doesn't want to upgrade angular 5 to angular 6 all of a sudden.

[Angular 6 disableOptionCentering example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khatke-sqizsf).

I would expect, the same behavior in version 5 is similar to how it works inversion.

I have tried using "panelClass" and it is working only in some cases, 
For example, when the option is selected (particularly the option should be in middle in the list) and then click on the dropdown, it shows the overlay pane aligned in the center position, not be below or above the field.

[Please follow the link which I have worked on](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-dyhaak).

I expect the output of Overlay Pane position for the mat-select just to be below or above on it.